# Why does adding the error case break my implementation of last?

Tags: list, haskell

This code works perfectly fine:

```
last' :: [a] -> a
last' (x:[]) = x
last' (x:xs) = last xs
```

But if I try to add:

```
last' [] = error "Empty list"
```

Anywhere. I get this error:

```
"Couldn't match type 'a' with [Char] -> a0' 
'a' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for last' :: [a] -> a
In the expression: error 
in any equation for last': last [] = error "Empty list"
```

Why is this? My implementations of head, tail and init did not scream when I put in the case for the empy list.

I'm an idiot. I had typos. Thanks!

Comment: Still have that error?

Comment: This line `last' (x:xs) = last xs` calls the built-in version of `last` on the RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `error` is not breaking your code. This should be the correct implementation:

```
last' :: [a] -> a
last' (x:[]) = x
last' (x:xs) = last' xs  -- xs not x
last' [] = error "Empty list"
```

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo on the 3rd line.

I also misspelled error which was probably breaking it. Too tired, should sleep then code.

Why is checking for error the last one to be done instead of the first?

Comment: @user2415706 In this case it doesn't matter. But it's a good habit to put it first.